# Why use amount.token to initialize Paid variable?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, corda

I am going through the Corda R3 training course and I am making headway, but when asked to create a Paid variable initialized to 0, the answer is:

```
package net.corda.training.state

import net.corda.core.contracts.Amount
import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import java.util.*

/**
 * This is where you'll add the definition of your state object. Look at the unit tests in [IOUStateTests] for
 * instructions on how to complete the [IOUState] class.
 *
 * Remove the "val data: String = "data" property before starting the [IOUState] tasks.
 */
data class IOUState(val amount: Amount<Currency>,
                    val lender: Party,
                    val borrower: Party,
                    val paid: Amount<Currency> = Amount(0, amount.token) ):
        ContractState {
            override val participants: List<Party> get() = listOf()
            }
```

Now I understand that we need to cast the value to type Amount, but why amount.token? I took the solution from:

https://github.com/corda/corda-training-solutions/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/training/state/IOUState.kt

Also, the task was to define it as Pounds, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

I find the reference for Pounds under:

https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.finance/kotlin.-int/index.html

I just do not understand how I would define the function.

Anyone have any pointers or suggestions for me? This code compiles and the tests pass, but I want to understand why... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The token simply indicates what this is an amount of.

So when used here:

```
val paid: Amount<Currency> = Amount(0, amount.token)
```

You're taking whatever token was used for the amount parameter e.g. POUNDS, DOLLARS etc and setting the paid Amount to the same token type.

Take a look at how it's done in currencies.kt in Corda